# ngx-swiper-wrapper: Cube, Coverflow and Flip

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, swiper.js

I am using ngx-swiper-wrapper and have yet to find the effects Cube, Coverflow and Flip, which are amazing in the original Swiper. Has anyone managed to find them? Are they part of ngx-swipper-wrapper?

ngx-swipper-wrapper:
https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper

The effects I'm looking for are demoed here:
http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found it! Checkout:

// Effects

```
fadeEffect?: SwiperFadeEffectInterface,
flipEffect?: SwiperFlipEffectInterface,
cubeEffect?: SwiperCubeEffectInterface,
coverflowEffect?: SwiperCoverflowEffectInterface,
```

https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper/blob/master/src/lib/swiper.interfaces.ts

Comment: I have yet to get this working. Can you provide a pointer on how you got the effects to work? thanks.

Comment: Below is my implementation. You'll notice the similarities with the official Swiper API. Sorry for the formatting!

`public pagination: SwiperPaginationInterface = {
    //
  };

  public autoplay: SwiperAutoplayInterface = {
    //
  };

  public config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
    pagination: this.pagination,
    threshold: 50,
    spaceBetween: 5,
    centeredSlides: true,
    speed: 3000,
    autoplay: this.autoplay,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    preventClicks: false,
    // Slide Effects:
    // slide, cube, flip, fade, coverflow
    effect: 'coverflow'
  };`

Comment: Given: Global config in module + use as directive; Then: one must pass the config from the Global config to the directive from the component. I assumed (wrongly apparently) that since the global config was available, well, globally, the directive would just pick it up and run with it. Nope. All set though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! I hope what I linked was also helpful for the configuration! I would have added more but Stackoverflow limits the amount of characters in a comment.

Comment: I lost the shadows on the coverflow effect. v1.3.6 works v2.4.0+ doesn't.

Comment: I haven't noticed, haha!